# FourierTransform does not transform a function on a non-uniform grid?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have trouble generating the FourierTransform of a function:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -0.5}, {1, -0.5 < x < 0}, {2, 
     0 < x < 1.7}, {3, 1.7 < x < 2}}];
F[u_] := f[u 2/Pi]
Plot[F[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "f_n(t)"}]
```

The series work out well:

```
    FourierSeries[F[u], u, 20];
Plot[%, {u, -Pi, Pi}]
```

However, the Fourier transform "fails" ?:

```
   G[\[Omega]_] := FourierTransform[F[u], u, \[Omega]]
p3 = Plot[Evaluate[Re[F[\[Omega]]]], {\[Omega], -Pi, 4 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "G_(\[Omega])"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I get only a text suggesting "Construct pure function"

When I plot this, I get this weird plot:

[image]

I have no idea what happens. Any suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: That plot is your function F[ ], not a plot of the Fourier output. Just change the Evaluate[Re[F[\[Omega]]]] to Evaluate[Re[G[\[Omega]]]] to see G[ ].

Comment: The Subject is misleading I think. This does not seem to have anything to do with a grid, regular or otherwise.

Comment: The problem is that the FourierTransform command does not give out a specific analytic function, it just writes "FourierTransform[G[\omega]]" nothing else

Comment: `In[248]:= 
f[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -0.5}, {1, -0.5 < x < 0}, {2, 
     0 < x < 1.7}, {3, 1.7 < x < 2}}];
bigF[u_] := f[u 2/Pi]
ft = FourierTransform[bigF[u], u, w]

Out[250]= 1/(
 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] w) ((0. + 
     1. I) + (0. + 1. I) E^((0. - 0.785398 I) w) - (0. + 
      2. I) E^((0. + 2.67035 I) w) + 
   6. Cos[2.90597 w] Sin[0.235619 w] + 
   4. E^((0. - 1.9635 I) w)
     Sin[1.1781 w] + (0. + 6. I) Sin[0.235619 w] Sin[2.90597 w])` So it appears to be working just fine.

Comment: A bug in my version? I tried to restart it but I got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f := (Piecewise[{{2, -2 < # < -0.5}, {1, -0.5 < # < 0}, {2, 
      0 < # < 1.7}, {3, 1.7 < # < 2}}] &)
F[u_] := f[u 2/Pi]
Plot[F[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f_n(t)"}]
```

f can be written as integral over DiracDelta with support at the step points or directly as a sum over HeavisideTheta steps with the step size.

```
h[x_] = 2 +Integrate[ - DiracDelta[x + 1/2] + DiracDelta[x] +DiracDelta[x - 17/10], x]

2 + HeavisideTheta[x] - HeavisideTheta[1 + 2 x] +  HeavisideTheta[-17 + 10 x]
```

FourierTransforms of all integrals and drivatives of step functions are implemented

```
k[\[Omega]_] =  FourierTransform[h[x], x, \[Omega]]  // Simplify

I   (1 - E^(-((I \[Omega])/2)) + E^((17 I \[Omega])/10))/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Omega]) + 
      (Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] + 2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) DiracDelta[\[Omega]]
```

The so called regularization of DiracDelta is the replacement of Delta by a NormalDistribution[0,s] that converges to Delta as s-> 0 for all "reasonable" smooth integrable functions under the  integral  over R

```
rk[\[Omega]_, s_] = k[\[Omega]] /. {DiracDelta[u_] :> 1/Sqrt[\[Pi] s] Exp[- u2^2/s]}

Plot[Re@rk[\[Omega], 0.1 ] , {\[Omega], -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Forier Thetas]

By manipulationg s one can differentiate poles and deltas in the Fourier plot.

Compare it to the  approximation over the finite interval you get by

```
G[\[Omega]_] := FourierTransform[F[u], u, \[Omega]]
p3 = Plot[Evaluate[Re[F[\[Omega]]]], {\[Omega], -Pi, 4 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "G_(\[Omega])"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Fourier Piecewise]